# How to install YouCompleteMe using pathogen on windows

Tags: vim, autocomplete, pathogen

I am trying to install YCM using Pathogen, however there isn't a tutorial to do this using Pathogen in the README file on Github. Is there any way to install YCM with Pathogen and how can I do so?

Comment: Just curious - what's wrong with using Vundle with the [instructions here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#windows)?

Comment: I am used to using Pathogen when installing other plugins and was curious if there was any way of doing so, as it might have made my life easier since I don't have or use Vundle.

Comment: @A.Hurtado, this is so common I have written a ruby script to handle installing plugins via Pathogen: https://github.com/zhon/vim-sitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a plugin with Pathogen you just need to put its folder inside your `%USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/` folder.

One way to do it would be:

```
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe
```

And then follow the rest of the installation instructions as if it were Vundle (check [the repo](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#windows) for more info):

```
cd %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe
python install.py --all
```

Answer (score 1):

On macOS using pyenv, I had to…

```
cd "$HOME/.vim/bundle"
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive  # I had to do this several times… YMMV
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.6.12
pyenv local 3.6.12
python3.6 install.py --all
```